# Why `this` keyword need to be evaluated inside this function?

Tags: javascript, this

Can anyone help me to explain the role of `this` keyword in this snippet. I'm reading `JS: The Definitive Guide` and run into this one:

```
// Define the ES5 String.trim() method if one does not already exist.
// This method returns a string with whitespace removed from the start and end.
String.prototype.trim = String.prototype.trim || function() 
{
   if (!this) 
    return this; // WHY EVALUATE `this` IN THIS FUNCTION???

    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
};
```

Comment: @elclanrs, But this `trim` method is augmented from `String` class already, why we need to evaluate if it is a `String object` again?

Comment: There is basically *zero benefit* to that test, and it only breaks the expected semantics of the native `.trim()` method. You should remove it. *..."Definitive Guide"* ...yeah, right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well this test

```
if (!this) return this;
```

means that if the string is empty so that it returns `this` which is in that case an empty string.

if you remove this test, the function still work, but keeping it will make the function faster because you don't have to call the `replace` function when the string is empty.

note that this test `if (!this) return this;` isn't for `null` or `undefined` values because they don't have a function inside them to call the proof is that we can't just do this :

```
undefined.trim();
null.trim();
```

Comment: Tks you @Khalid, that makes sense to me!

Comment: @babygau, Khalid: This really isn't quite right. Unless in strict mode, no matter what the string, the `this` value will be "truthy", and so `this` will not be returned. The reason is that `this` will *not* be a `string` primitive, but rather a `String` object wrapper. If it is in strict mode, then the `.trim()` method will be supported natively. So you should remove this test since it just makes no sense and only adds unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Also, `this` *can* be `null` or `undefined` when in strict mode. The proper approach would not be to do `return this`, but rather to throw the proper error as required by ECMAScript.

Comment: ...also, when in strict mode, there are other "falsey" values that ought to return their `toString()` value rather than returning the original value. It really just breaks things more than anything, and will never really offer any real benefit. Only in strict mode, when the method is invoked on an empty primitive string will the `.replace()` be avoided... and the benefit of this will probably be non-existent. But again, in browsers that support strict mode, they will already have `.trim()` method.

Comment: Sorry dude, but almost everything in this answer is wrong. I have no idea why six people have given it +1. :-(

Answer (score -1):

Most likely if `this` is `undefined` or `null`, it works as error detection.

```
if (!string.trim()) { alert("string is null or undefined."); }
```

Comment: undefined or null don't have a function inside them to call

Comment: `String.prototype.trim.call(null)` will give `null` when in strict mode.